# Given $ax^n = 2^k$ is it possible to calculate $k$ if $a$, $x$ and $n$ are known

Tags: exponentiation

For example, we know that:

$2.143483648 * 10^9 = 2^{31}$

If we were given:

$2.143483648 * 10^9 = 2^k$

How do we find $k$ ?

Comment: You can use logarithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm

Comment: @Botond thanks. Would you care to turn that into an answer with a worked example in terms of the values given above and I will accept.

Comment: Yes, I did it. Is it understandable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if we take the $\log_2$ of both sides, we get that
$$\log_2(ax^n) =\log_2(2^k)$$
$$log_2(a)+\log_2(x^n)=k$$
$$k=\log_2(a)+n\log_2(x)$$
In your example, $a=2.143483648$, $x=10$, $n=9$, which means that
$$k=\log_2(2.143483648)+9\log_2(10)$$
Which is [approximately 31](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log(2,%202.143483648)%2B9log(2,10)), as you expected.

Comment: That is very cool. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

If $$x=2^k$$
then if we take logarithm of both sides,

$$\ln(x)=\ln(2^k)=k\ln(2)$$

thus

$$k=\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(2)}=\log_{2}(x)$$